# While reading csv file through url I want to map column name with data

Tags: java, csv

While reading csv file through url I want to map column name with file data

Example

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 5 6 
2 3 4 6
```

Output should be

```
No1 No3 
1    3   
2    5   
2    4
```

So particular columns are to be imported with following mapping. No1 no3

Can we use `ArrayList` for that? Right now I am using array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question? What problems are you facing?

Comment: It's hard to say what to do as you didn't include any related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an ArrayList to store values respect to a column, better yet a Hashmap to contain all the values. I am assuming you have a 2D array to contain the values if so you can do this,

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfColumnss; i++){
   List<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int j=0; j < numberOfRows; j++){
      myArrayList.add(myArray[j][i])
   }
   myMap.put(i, myArrayList)
}
```